# Error: no results found for query

Tags: android, parse-platform

When I've tried to run this code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    query.getInBackground(FbLogin.userObjId, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
      public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            ...
        } else {
          Log.e("tag", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    });
```

The "FbLogin.userObjId" is the parse user ID:

```
userObjId = (String) user.get("objectId");
```

Well, when I've tried to run this code, I got this message:

```
11-27 13:48:32.827: E/tag(27174): Error: no results found for query
```

What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Might be user id is wrong or invalid.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I don't see any reason why the user id will be wrong or invalid... I think that something is wrong on the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
userObjId = (String) user.get("objectId");
```

I wrote:

```
userObjId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
```